# How does this code in liferay works

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Please explain what does the following code do:

```
boolean showButton = ParamUtil.getBoolean(request, "showButton", true);
PortletSession psession = renderRequest.getPortletSession();
```

Answer (score 3):

The code [`ParamUtil.getBoolean(request, "showButton", true);`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/ParamUtil.java#L38) retrieves the value of parameter `showButton` from the request object passed.

It is just synonymous to the call `request.getParameter("showButton")` but additionally it also converts the `String` value of the parameter to `boolean` i.e. if the string values are `"true"`, `"t"`, `"y"`, `"on"`, `"1"` they would get converted to boolean `true`.